# Can you use jquery to get the selected value one dropdown list while in the javascript function of another dropdownList

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Can you use jQuery to get the  selected value one dropdown list while in the JavaScript function  of another dropdownList

This works fine when its in the JavaScript for the specific DropDownList "ddlSelectedRole"

```
var  ddListSelectedValue =  $("#ddlSelectedRole").val();
```

But I need this value again when working in another dropdown list's JavaScript function,
but it wont return the selected value while I'm in the function for another dropdownlost

Comment: How do you try to get that value in the event you mentioned above?

Comment: There's some relevant code missing here. Instead of just explaining via text *where you are* and *what you're doing*, please include that code.

Answer (score 0):

What you have works fine, you just need to put it inside a function that occurs when you change the other drop down list.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pLwSh/1/)

```
$('#ddlOther').on('change', function() {
    var  ddListSelectedValue =  $("#ddlSelectedRole").val();
    alert(ddListSelectedValue);
});
```